# Does Safari has a panel similar with Chrome's Preview under Network?

Tags: safari

In Safari, if I request gets a 403 error, there is only a sample hint.

[image]

But in the Chorome, there have a Preview panel under Network.

[image]

Whether is Safari has a similar panel but I don't know? 
Or do not have this panel?

---

**EDIT**

The relate resource. I opened all of the right tabs, no one like Chrome's Network Preview tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the underlined URL shown on the right of the error. This opens the Resources tab with all the request and response details in the right sidebar.

Comment: I tested that before ask the question, there is no preview tab.

Comment: @aircraft No, but the information is shown in the right sidebar.

Comment: Yes, you right. but you see, I am seeking a tab like Chrome's Preview,  you can see my snapshot, that panel shows the details, the issue caused by missing CSRF token. but the safari do not have that panel to show this detail message.